# Why does Allah use prophets to spread his message to humanity?

Tags: allah, islamic-philosophy, prophets

Through out the ages, Allah has sent prophets amongst mankind to spread his message of compassion, mercy and obedience to his will. But this system is open to abuse by the unworthy among men, masquerading as prophets for their own selfish ends. It would be far more credible if Allah would speak to each human being individually, yet instead he uses prophets, including Jesus (PBUH) and the last and greatest, Mohammad (PBUH).

Rather than communicating with humanity individually, why does Allah instead use prophets to spread his message to humanity?

Comment: Prophets are creation of GOD, so they are controlled by GOD . They can't do anything in their own , so messages of prophets are messages of GOD itself

Comment: @tachyons: So prophets are just pupets!

Comment: @tachyons I disagree that prophets are 'controlled' by God. They are humans and they have free will. However I agree that all our actions (and the prophets') are expected (or planned) by God. Indeed this is a hard question regarding free will and Allah knows the best.

Comment: Mohammad (PBUH) is the last prophet yes, but the greatest? I recall a verse from Quran that we should not compare prophets like such, I'm trying to find it. If anyone finds it please put it here.

Comment: I found it. [see link](http://quran.com/2/285). "We make no distinction between any of His messengers."

Answer (score 3):

There is no doubt that God is able to tell us his law by himself or through his angels or revelation ...

But the mercy of God that he sent us messengers from humans, speak like us and think like us ...

If God sent us angels and told us  his law, so was difficult for us to apply that law, and we say that this king is not human, while he made ​​God's messengers from human to tell us God's law and **how to apply them.**

Allah said:

> قُل لَّوْ كَانَ فِي الْأَرْضِ مَلَائِكَةٌ يَمْشُونَ مُطْمَئِنِّينَ
>   لَنَزَّلْنَا عَلَيْهِم مِّنَ السَّمَاءِ مَلَكًا رَّسُولا
>
> Say: "If angels had peopled the earth and walked about in peace and
>   quiet, We would surely have sent to them an angel as messenger.[17:95]

Comment: Would you agree with the following? Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) is designated as Prophet instead of 'sent', because he was just like us before the revelation. However Jesus is 'sent' to us, because Allah ordained 'be' and it be, he is the son of Virgin Mary as a miracle.

Answer (score 2):

I think if Allah directly talked to me and said: "Believe in me!", my belief was not valuable anymore!

Believe in Allah is valuable and praised because it's a decision - not a force.

Even for the case of prophets, Allah did not talk them just after their birth, but they’ve grown, they’ve proven their belief in Allah during their life, they showed their capacity to be a prophet, they were examined many times with hardest exams and then they were selected by Allah to be prophet. Even most of them received the messages of Allah not directly, but through the angels or a different way:

> و ما کان لبشر أن یکلمه اللّه إلا وحیا أو من وراء حجاب أو یرسل رسولا
>   فیوحی باذنه ما یشاء إنه علی‌ حکیم

Comment: Actually there are prophets who were chosen as prophet while they were kids, Jesus [19:29,30] and John [19:12] peace be upon them being two. Even Joseph peace be upon him was sent his first inspiration while he was kid, see [12:15].

Comment: +1 I completely agree with your first two paragraphs and @owari 's comment.

Answer (score 1):

Assalamu alaikum warahmatullaahi wabarakaatuh

Is it appropriate for a Great King to speak to each of his subjects? He would send a messenger to convey his orders, just as Allah the most high sent messengers with clear proofs.

Quran - And Moses had certainly brought you clear proofs. Then you took the calf [in worship] after that, while you were wrongdoers. (2:92)

The miracles they were sent with enable us to differentiate the real Prophets from impostors.

And Allah knows best.

Comment: We're talking about a supreme being of immense power that can do anything - Allah. Whereas a mere king is a humanbeing like the rest of us.

Comment: @owari I said supreme being, not supreme humanbeing :)

Comment: @LarryHarson, thanks, my misunderstanding, I deleted my comment :)

Comment: @LarryHarson Are you sure Allah is a being? I think we know not.

Answer (score 0):

According to Quran, God is close to everyone, closer than their vein in the neck, however we the humans are not necessarily close to God to hear His messages! So those who can hear are chosen and introduced as prophets and for them are defined missions to send us the messages!

What is said above is not really wrong although it is not the way the issue is usually discussed. God is beyond His creations, so beyond time and space, no creation of God can ever fully understand a notion beyond the limits of creation, we cannot even fully understand ourselves! What is really important is to know who we are, not who God is! Where we are and that why are we here? Where we have come from and where we are going to be? Our main questions are concerning ourselves. These are questions that everyone may ask himself just at any rare moment that he deeply thinks of himself and care his own being, off from the routines of everyday life. These are not merely theoretical questions in the sense of pure mathematics, these can have very serious application to our everyday life as well. If we know why we are here then we can focus on the reason why we are here and plan our rest of life based on such understandings and etc. However, the adventure of finding proper and satisfactory answers to these MOST-IMPORTANT questions needs somewhat intelligence, honesty not to ignore the facts --in believing level-- in the favor of desires, strong will not to ignore the facts --in the action level-- in the favor of laziness or withstanding people's mocking and things like that, responsibility and maybe some other characteristics. Not everyone can individually find the truth and adhere to it in his own life. However, there have been also many who could accomplish this, they were all known in their own societies as wise, reasonable, trustworthy, honest, energetic, caring about the others, responsible, mild and etc. then have one day seen or heard a strange being introducing himself an angel of God stating that God has chosen him --now that he has survived-- help His other creature to survive as well. This is again a simplified version of the whole story. We have had prophets that were previously announced by another prophet that he will become a prophet, we have had prophets that were left free to choose if they want to be prophet or not, and Luqman --peace be upon him-- who was eligible for the position but didn't choose to become a prophet, since he was wise, more wise than the one who chose to become a prophet in a similar situation!

Those who ask why Allah doesn't show himself more explicitly to us, so that we can see or hear Him, scholars bring them an analogy. Break a mirror in very tiny parts, take one part and hold it in your front, can you see yourself in it? No, you may see an eye, your nose, your lips, but not the complete body. So the suggestion is for the mirror to be bigger. Here we are all mirrors for Allah, his creations, anyone who has enlarged his mirror-ness he would find Allah reflected in his being more clearly. Human can reach a place that Imam Hussain --peace be upon him-- reached when he was whispering with his God in his [Arafe Dua](http://www.wakingvoice.com/1391/08/03/imam-hosseinas-arafe-dua-english-translation/):

> اِلهی تَرَدُّدی فی الاْآثارِ یُوجِبُ بُعْدَ الْمَزارِ فَاجْمَعْنی
>   عَلَیْکَ بِخِدْمَةٍ تُوصِلُنی اِلَیْکَ. کَیْفَ یُسْتَدَلُّ عَلَیْکَ
>   بِما هُوَ فی وُجودِهِ مُفْتَقِرٌ اِلَیْکَ؟ اَیَکُونُ لِغَیْرِکَ مِنَ
>   الظُّهُورِ ما لَیْسَ لَکَ حَتّی یَکُونَ هُوَ الْمُظْهِرُ لَکَ، مَتی
>   غِبْتَ حَتّی تَحْتاجَ اِلی دَلیلٍ یَدُلُّ عَلَیْکَ وَمَتی بَعُدْتَ
>   حَتّی تَکُونَ الاْآثارُ هِیَ الَّتی تُوصِلُ اِلَیْکَ؟ عَمِیَتْ عَیْنٌ
>   لا تَراکَ عَلَیْها رَقیبا وَخَسِرَتْ صَفْقَةُ عَبْدٍ لَمْ تَجْعَلْ
>   لَهُ مِنْ حُبِّکَ نَصیبا
>
> O my God, my hesitation in (following) Your traces will result in
>   unlikely visitation; so, (please) join me to You through a service
>   that takes me to You. How can You be figured out through that whose
>   existence relies on You? Can any thing other than You hold a (kind of)
>   manifestation that You lack and thus it may act as an appearance for
>   You? When have You ever been absent so that You may need something to
>   point to You? When have You ever been far-off so that traces may lead
>   to You? **Blind be the eye that cannot see You watching it** [*by eyes here eyes of hearth  are meant and not eyes of face of course*]. Losing
>   is a servant’s deal that does not dedicate a share to the love for
>   You.

Anyway, the prophecy is the position to bring the special messages of God to the people not being aware of the messages otherwise, but this doesn't mean that seeing the angels or hearing to them or even hearing the messages of Allah Himself is limited to the prophets. There are many who were not prophets but could see and hear the angels (examples are in Quran, the Virgin Mary, the wife of Abraham, Luqmaan, peace be upon them and etc) and heard the messages of Allah, actually not every message is a rule, the rules are necessarily stated by the prophets but even you and me may have heard some inspirations and messages from God deep to our hearts, this is what we call Elhaam (inspiration maybe?). Even animals have this inspiration like Quran reports it about bees. For many of us for whom there are some darknesses in our hearth it is not always easy to make sure if an inspiration to our hearth is necessarily correct from Allah or maybe corrupted and fake from evils, but for those who have been purified there would be no doubt that the inspiration is from God and hence truth, so that we see prophets in history to whom God was talking, through His angels while they were asleep. While we cannot always rely on our dreams but the prophets' dreams are always honest dreams.

**EDIT.** Also let me add this that every prophet was also a good pattern for his people, so that no one can claim he was not able to live by the laws of God at his time, since there have been at least one person among them at the same time that was living by the rules of God, in more or less similar situations. So that God has always sent His rules with a guide who can interpret the rule for different situations and himself is a good pattern to learn from.

Comment: "What is really important is to know who we are, not who God is!". Well I don't think this is true. Islam means submission to the will of Allah, not to oneself.

Comment: @LarryHarson, you are right but Allah needs not our submission but we do it for our own benefit, as we should know Allah and pray Him to know ourselves and improve toward the target Allah has defined for us. Allah is the Needless. "Who God is?" is a question that we should answer before we can start evolving toward the target defined for us.

Answer (score 0):

The whole design of this universe is made up for a TEST of human beings. And that test is whether we believe in our Creator or not after watching billions of signs of His existence in ourselves and as well as in the whole universe.

Quran: 41:53 http://quran.com/41/53 (Mohsin ali translation)

> We will show them Our Signs in the universe, and in their ownselves,
>   until it becomes manifest to them that this (the Quran) is the truth.
>   Is it not sufficient in regard to your Lord that He is a Witness over
>   all things?

No matter what type of things you start researching at. You will get to two points.

1. One point would be that YES there is a Creator. Zillions of ultra complex things can't come out of nothing and keep operating to their perfect level without anyone Creating & controlling them. You may start researching about as big as whole universe and as small as an atom.
2. The second point is, okay then where is that Creator? Now you start looking for him no matter what physical or mental tools you use, you will never be able to see His physical existence. This is all part of the design of our test.

Quran: 6:103 http://quran.com/6/103 (Mohsin ali translation)

> No vision can grasp Him, but His Grasp is over all vision. He is the
>   Most Subtle and Courteous, Well-Acquainted with all things.

The part of the design is also that nothing will be revealed from Allah until the day of judgment that we will be able to see and talk to our Creator; or our Creator talks to us.

If there were angels living in the earth, then Allah would have sent angels for us. See the verse below.

Quran: 17:95 http://quran.com/17/95 (Mohsin ali translation)

> Say: "If there were on the earth, angels walking about in peace and
>   security, We should certainly have sent down for them from the heaven
>   an angel as a Messenger."

Here in Quran Allah tells why he sent human Prophets on earth.

Quran: 25:20, http://quran.com/25/20 (Mohsin ali translation)

> And We never sent before you (O Muhammad SAW) any of the Messengers
>   but verily, they ate food and walked in the markets. And We have made
>   some of you as a trial for others: will you have patience? And your
>   Lord is Ever All-Seer (of everything).

Answer (score 0):

AOA....if Allah would himself say me or send an angel to tell me to believe in Him we would be bound to do so because we would have already seen his actual presence or the presence of one of his greatest signs angel and all the tests for our faith will be over

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE. Please consider taking our [tour], checking our [help] and [meta] to learn more about the site. And read [answer] to learn what we expect an appropriate answer to look like!

Answer (score 0):

A teacher (in this case Allah) won't give you the answers in a test.....they're going to be watching and might send you signs if they really love you as a student when your stuck (which Allah does, one of his 99 name is "Al Wudud" meaning benevolent ), hence he sent the prophets to give us the signs. He is also "Al Hādīy" and "Al Rashid" meaning he will guide you and hes the right way. You just have to open your eyes and look around you.

If God gave us all the answers to things...it would be too complex for us to understand. Imagine if I actually got every answer to my question and I tell a non-believer, they would think of me as abnormal and crazy because of the complexity of the answers. 
You don't need the answers to everything to believe.

Your parents love you and it's present but most of the time they don't tell you. But you know it's true from the gestures they do e.g. Give you food, clothes. 
You dont need to see something for you to believe in it. 
You need to be able to pick up on signs and actions which explain things.

Keep on smiling :)

Answer (score -1):

Assalamualaikum wa rahmatullahi wa barkatuh. Allah hu Akbar. Allah does what He wants how He wants and if we are patient and think deep enough, in shaa Allah we will find the answers. But to believe and truly understand we must stop disobeying His laws.

The answer to the question in shaa Allah is:
We all know that if a Prophet was to disobey Allah by sinning, his punishment is much greater than any other humans. Imagine Allah decided we all are like the Prophet's i.e, we receive direct messages. Then His Mercy on us will be less than what we have now because not all of us have the retaining power like the Prophet's. The Prophet's don't sin, but us, constantly. It's like a constant for us to sin. But what can make us believe is the signs of Allah. Allah is true as you cannot explain your being and cannot deny His existence when you are existing. His Al Quran is true as there's nothing in there but guidance for all humanity. And Nabi Muhammad SallAllahu Alayhi wassalam is true, what has he gained of worldly needs? He is a leader but you can never tell. The way you can tell is by looking well and seeing that this man is different from the others. And Allah does not show Himself to us because, take this example, the unbeliever won't enter Jannah. So if the unbeliever can see Allah Who is better than Jannah, then what's the point of Jahannam? It's good that you asked. We all need guidance and Allah can use several ways to guide us.

And Allah Knows best. 
Alhamdulillah.

Answer (score -4):

All The answers are correct but Let me Give You an Example.
Like in the Modern world You want to do a SMS but your relative dont have a mobile phone so he cannot read the signals himself,he have to get a mobile phone which will tell the message to him..So thats why God sent prophets so that they can understand and deliver the message to us...I hope it will clear you confusion